# Why current working directory affects install path of setup.py? How to prevent that?

Tags: python, python-3.6, setup.py

I have created a custom python package following [this guide](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html), so I have the following structure:

```
mypackage/     <-- VCS root
  mypackage/
    submodule1/
    submodule2/
  setup.py
```

And setup.py contains exactly the same information as in the guide:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='0.1',
      description='desc',
      url='vcs_url',
      author='Hodossy, Szabolcs',
      author_email='myemail@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=[
          # deps
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I have noticed if I go into the folder where setup.py is, and then call `python setup.py install` in a virtual environment, in site-packages the following structure is installed:

```
.../site-packages/mypackage-0.1-py3.6.egg/mypackage/
  submodule1/
  submodule2/
```

but if I call it from one folder up like `python mypackage/setup.py install`, then the structure is the following:

```
.../site-packages/mypackage-0.1-py3.6.egg/mypackage/
  mypackage/
    submodule1/
    submodule2/
```

This later one ruins all imports from my module, as the path is different for the submodules.

Could you explain what is happening here and how to prevent that kind of behaviour?

This is experienced with Python 3.6 on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup.py does not contain any paths, but seems to only find the files via `find_packages`. So of course it depends from where you run it. The setup.py isn't strictly tied to its location. Of course you could do things like `chdir` to the `basename` of the setup file path in `sys.argv[0]`, but that's rather ugly.

The question is, WHY do you want to build it that way? It looks more like you would want a structure like

```
mypackage-source
  mypackage
    submodule1
    submodule2
  setup.py
```

And then execute setup.py from the work directory. If you want to be able to run it from anywhere, the better workaround would be to put a shellscript next to it, like

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ``basename $0``
python setup.py $@
```

which separates the task of changing to the right directory (here I assume the directory with setup.py in the workdir) from running setup.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I should not use find_packages, as it will cause inconsistent installs of my package.

Comment: I think you should use it, but make sure from which directory you start your build. To phrase it another way: you could run the setup.py from any directory and build the packages in there, as it does not specify any absolute paths. That's on purpose, because you never know how the directory layout is where somebody else may be building it. So the packages are collected starting from the current directory. I think you need to have one subfolder more in the hierarchy, even when it looks like it would be redundant. Something like ``mypackage-source/mypackage/submodule1``